# ??My samsung s9 lost the OS when i did a factory reset??? HELP MEEE

Tags: samsung

CAN SOMEONE PLEASE HELP ME WITH A WAY TO REINSTALL THE OS TO MY S9, MY PHONE USES A PROGRAMMED APP CALLED "TEAM WIN RECOVERY PROJECT" AND IT IS THE ONLY THJING THAT WORKS ON MY S9
PLEASE HELP ME
THANKS

Comment: maybe you just switched slots? who installed twrp? how exactly did you factory reset? just a hint questions with please help me are most likely ignored

Answer (score 0):

TWRP is a custom recovery with many useful features, one of which is the ability to backup all partitions.  If you have a system backup you could just flash it via TWRP.  If by chance you don't you can search your specific carrier device on XDA and flash a custum rom.  Contrary to popular belief, flashing a customer rom doesn't necessarily mean rooting your device.
Another option is to download the official factory firmware from Sammobile and flash it  using a pc programe  called Odin.  You may also find official factory firmware avaliable for download from XDA links.   Smart switch is another option  you may consider looking into.  I should warn that some updates may lock your bootloader or prevent downgrade to lower OS's.
Whether you choose custom or factory always use an Md5 checker to confirm the validity of your download.